# Ionic 2: Can I pass a page as an argument to navCtrl.push?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm starting to work with Ionic and I'd like to use a single function for navigation instead of one for each link, and pass the page as an argument on the event. For example, this works fine:

```
navRegisterPage(){
  this.navCtrl.push(RegisterPage);
}

navLoginPage(){
  this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
}
```

But I'd like to do something like:

```
goToPage(page){
  this.navCtrl.push(page);
}
```

and pass the page as an argument like this:

```
<button ion-button secondary (click)="goToPage(RegisterPage)">Ingresar</button>
```

Can this be done? I tried it but keep getting an error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): invalid views to insert"

Comment: You missed '' around RegisterPage in (click)="goToPage(RegisterPage). Should be (click)="goToPage('RegisterPage')"

Answer (score 1):

in lazy loading this works (passing the component name as a string):

`<button ion-button secondary (click)="goToPage("RegisterPage")">Ingresar</button>`

```
goToPage(page: string){
  this.navCtrl.push(page);
}
```

maybe it works in normal loading too, try it